# Dropdown menu on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have set up a wordpress dropdown menu to work in the theme I have created. It is working in so far as the second level child appears when you hover over the desired parent link in the menu, but the dropdown is appearing all the way off to the left of the menu instead of under the one it should. To test it, go to [THIS SITE](http://new.freedomenergy.co.nz/).

How do I get it to appear below the one I want it to. Hover over "Solar Electricity" to see the test. It comes out under Home instead of where it should.

The css I'm using is:

```
/* sub menus!!  */

ul.dropdown ul {
    background-color:#383530;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0; /* Appear just below the hovering list */
    padding:0.6em;
    width:200px; /* specify the width. */
    position:absolute; /* needed */
    z-index:500; /* specify the order */
}

ul.dropdown li ul {
    top:27px; /* Positioning:Calc with top level horz list height */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 10px #000; /* CSS 3 */
}

ul.dropdown ul ul {
    top:0;
    left:100%; /* Position the sub menus to right. */
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    float:none; /* umm.. Appear below the previous one. mmkay? */
}

/* Drop Down! */

/* Hide all the dropdowns (submenus) */
ul.dropdown ul,
ul.dropdown li:hover ul ul,
ul.dropdown ul li:hover ul ul
{ display: none; }

/* Display the submenus only when li are hovered */
ul.dropdown li:hover ul,
ul.dropdown ul li:hover ul ,
ul.dropdown ul li ul li:hover ul
{ display: block;}

ul.dropdown li * a:hover {
    /* Change color of links when hovered */
    background: #600;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #200, #400); /* CSS 3 */
    border-bottom:1px solid #900;
    border-top:1px solid #222;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:inline-block` instead of `display:inline` to following rule in your **style.css** at **line #206**

```
#menu li {
  display: inline-block; /* change this */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
}
```

Comment: ... sorry - now another issue has come up as a result. The dropdown appears too far right when that parent link or the one next to it is active. Any hints please?

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy Do one thing Add one more rule `position:relative` to your `#menu li` css and at **line# 293** Add `left:0` and it will fix the issue! :)

Comment: Oooo - one last thing has happened. The dropdown menu items now have small active tab backgrounds. How do I make the background image span the width of the dropdown? Also, if the parent menu item is any wider, then the smaller children start to stack side by side I noticed.

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy For the side by side issue you can set `width:100%`to `ul.dropdown ul li` class @ **line #329** in **style.css** And for the span background, right now i'm seeing it's width upto the dropdown! :)

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion has fixed the dropdown width, but I set it to 82% as there was an issue with the background. If you are on an active page from the dropdown menu, the background on the child menu item is too big at 100%. Thanks heaps again.

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy I'm not getting you what exactly you want! about background spans! :)

Comment: You need to actually select one of the items from the child menu - for example Grid Tied http://new.freedomenergy.co.nz/hydro/grid-tied/ and when you go back in to the menu, you will see that the active page has a background image behind it.

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy Ok Got it.. For that you need to **remove**  `padding:0.2em` Css rule from `ul.dropdown ul` class at **line  #310**

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't seem to fix it. I've tried that and it doesn't work. Take a look...

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy Aah. Got it you just set `overflow:hidden` CSS rule to `ul.dropdown li ul` class in **style.css** at **line# 319 ** Problem solved :)

Comment: Hey - I have one more small issue I've been trying to solve, but can't. The children menu items which are on the dropdown are black in font color when the parent page is active. I only ever want the children menu items to be black when that page itself is active, not when the parent is active (ie at the moment, when you hover over the parent again when it's active, all the childern have black font - which I don't want). Hope you can work your magic again for me! Thanks

Comment: @superflymonkeyboy Yes i can but not in this thread you can start a new thread because it will became too messy in this thread! Ask a question again and i'll help you!

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the three images in the other menu, with the duplicate dropdown menu displayed.

[image: help dropdownmenu wordpress bootstrap4]

**This is the code:**

```
  if( $args->walker->has_children && $depth == 0 ) {
              $output .= '<span class="caret down" onclick="myFunction()">';
          }
            $output .= '</span>';
}
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth=0, $args = array() ){
    $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
    $output .= "<ul id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-menu $submenu depth_$depth'>";

}
```

Comment: Your answer isn't very clear.  The narration at the beginning and the image don't make sense (or is difficult to understand) - would you mind clarifying?